# Function to find capital letters in a word

Tags: python, function, for-loop

There is function to find capital letters in a word and and returns the index of that letter in the list.

```
def capslock(word):
    res = []
    for i,j in enumerate(word):
        if j.isupper():
            res.append(i)
    return  res
print(capslock("JDhfjkShh"))

[0,1,6]


I don’t understand why if you swap the loop variables in places (like that)

def capslock(word):
    res = []
    for j,i in enumerate(word):
        if j.isupper():
            res.append(i)
    return  res
print(capslock("JDhfjkShh"))

it gives me  AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isupper'
```

I believe that the problem is that when the first variable is checked for the if condition in the loop and if the condition is met (the letter in the argument word is large), then the next variable remains empty and has nothing to return to result list . is my guess correct that first both variables should fall under the in enumerate function so that one variable checks the letter and the other puts it in the list - the result

I guess this is not a dumb question for a 6 day study.

updated:thanks for the feedback, you made it clear that this is still a stupid question, I will try not to distract you with this anymore

Comment: Print j and i in the loop and you will see

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: You're swapping variable names, but not what they do. `i` and `j` don't have any magical meaning, their value is because of the position that they're in. Check out the Python docs for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), and [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples).

Comment: The first parameter is index and the second parameter will be the value it doesn't matter if you swap the name!! it will remain same

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
caps="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def capslock(word):
    res = []
    for letter in range(len(word)):
        if word[letter] in caps:
            res.append(word[letter])
    return res
```

the code bellow will will check each letter and see if its inside `caps` if it is it will be added to `res`.
You can modify this code to get the index of the letter using `letter`

Example:

```
caps="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def capslock(word):
    res = []
    for letter in range(len(word)):
        if word[letter] in caps:
            res.append(letter)
    return res
```

this code will return the index instead of the letter itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd code you have swiped the name of the variables in the 4th and 5th line of the code

```
if i.isupper():
        res.append(j)
```

The code should be:

```
def capslock(word):
    res = []
    for j,i in enumerate(word):
        if i.isupper():
            res.append(j)
    return  res
print(capslock("JDhfjkShh"))
```

This will print `[0, 1, 6]`

since j is a int and i is a 'str'. You are getting this error

Answer (score 0):

following @Shounak Das code id like to improve it using comprehension list because it will be much faster than using a regular for

```
def capslock(word):
    return [index for index, letter in enumerate(word) if letter.isupper()]

print(capslock("ThisIsATittle"))
```

this will print `[0, 4, 6, 7]`

hope this was useful